# jQuery selector: How can I pass value from var colorid into selector?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
var obj = document.getElementById("<%= tbUpdate.ClientID %>");
    var colorid = obj.value;
    $('.shade[colorId=colorid]').addClass('active');
```

the problem is with the colorId=colorid. I think jQuery thinks that it's string. How can I pass value from var colorid into selector?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.shade[colorId=' + colorid + ']');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the value of `colorId` you would need to pass a string to the jQuery selector using concatenation`$('.shade[colorId=' + colorid + ']')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.shade[colorId=' + colorid + ']').addClass('active');
```