# Problems formatting jQuery statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a specific TR in my table.  Each TR ID ends with _rowX where X is the line number.  For example, _row1.

How can I find a specific TR in my table using the row number being passed into a function.  I'm having a problem formatting the code to find _row + the number being passed into the function.

For example:

```
function FindRow(row)
{
  var tr = $('[id $= "_row" + row]');

  tr.css(....
}
```

This fails because of the problem with the "'s.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently someone asked the same question a few hours ago.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818659/jquery-selector/5818691

Comment: Please note that ID attributes must start with a letter in the HTML 4 spec -- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
function FindRow(row)
{
  var tr = $('tr[id $="_row' + row +'"]');

  tr.css(....
}
```

Comment: Thank you Neal!  All the ' and " really gets confusing for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
function FindRow(row)
{
  var tr = $('#_row' + row);

  tr.css(....
}
```

### EDIT

If the ID *ends with* `_row<number>` then you should try Neil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#_row' + row );
```

ID's can be selected directly, no need to use [id=] syntax.